# User defined classes in Web2Py

Tags: python, class, web2py

I am a beginner in Web2Py. I wish to develop a simple application, where the user should log in with a username and a password (no fancy stuff like login with facebook or OpenID etc.). Upon successful login, the user sees some interface, and performs certain operations. I imagined a `User` class and a `JobStore` class (which has certain methods defined, which the user should be able to call). There will be only one JobStore object for all users and sessions. When a user logs in, an User object gets created with a reference to the JobStore. The User class has methods like `GetRights()`, `RequestJob()`, `MarkAsFinished()`, etc. and JobStore has methods like `GetUnfinished()`, `RemoveJobs()`, etc. Structurally speaking, where am I supposed to have these classes, so that based on certain actions the user performs on the view, certain methods get called? Are these classes supposed to inherit from some standard classes used in Web2Py? I am trying to find an example, where some kind of object oriented approach is used in the controller, but have not found any so far. Also, is this the wrong approach in Web2Py app development? I am not trying to implement any complex business logic through these functions as of now; I am just trying to understand how traditional programming approach would map to Web2Py approach somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define classes in model or controller files, but it would probably make most sense to put them in the app's /modules folder and import them where needed in your models and controllers. There is no need for your classes to inherit from web2py classes, though they can do so if desired. For more on using modules and importing, see [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Accessing-the-API-from-Python-modules) and [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04#Third-party-modules).

For an example of a heavily object-oriented approach, see the [Movuca](https://github.com/rochacbruno/Movuca) CMS. Most of the code is in the [/modules](https://github.com/rochacbruno/Movuca/tree/master/modules) folder.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just posted the question, so I hope you do not mind if I wait a bit before marking the correct answer.